# Emacs 23: Change Theme

Tags: themes

I have emacs version 23.3.1, the default color has dark purple text against a grey background which hurts my eyes.

I have read documentation* to try and look through the list of default preloaded emacs themes and pick a new color theme.

*where can I find emacs documentation specific to an older version?

I have tried M-x and the following commands, however all of them return with "[No Match]"

> M-x color-theme-select
>
> M-x customize-themes

When I try "customize-themes" on my local terminal I can see a list of themes and can pick between them (v24.5.1).

*Is there anyway to achieve this on the older version of emacs?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Custom* themes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomThemes) are not really available for Emacs releases prior to Emacs 24.  (They are available in a rudimentary form, which does not correspond to what you think of as a theme.)

But [*color* themes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemes) are available for pretty much any Emacs release.  You need library [`color-theme.el`](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) to use color themes.

Here are two libraries that you can use (either of them) to choose among available themes, *seeing the effect of each or any before choosing*. Each library lets you cycle among either color themes or custom themes.

- **[Do Re Mi](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi)** - commands **`doremi-color-themes+`** and **`doremi-custom-themes+`**
- **[Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)** - [(multi-)](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands)commands **`icicle-color-theme`** and **`icicle-custom-theme`**.

For Icicles, you have these user options:

- **`icicle-color-themes`** is a list of color themes to
  cycle through when you use command `icicle-color-theme`.
- Option **`icicle-custom-themes`** is a list of Emacs custom themes
  to cycle through when you use command `icicle-custom-theme`.
- Option **`icicle-custom-themes-accumulate-flag`** determines whether such
  cycling keeps the effects of previously applied themes or
  replaces each theme with the next one.
- Option **`icicle-custom-themes-update-flag`** determines whether the
  command automatically saves changes made.  A prefix argument
  flips this option value for the invocation of the command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still find this very confusing. We have libraries and packages dont fully understand what either of these things are. I clicked on the link for color-theme.el but I couldn't actually find the color-theme.el file or link for download anywhere. Even if I could download the file I wouldn't know where to put it or what to do with it. It all seems an inordinate amount of effort just to change the color scheme of my editor.

Comment: color-theme is here: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/color-theme.el.gz - uncompress it to color-theme.el. (That's from the Download link from the link I gave above.) Put a library in your `load-path`, then `require` it in your init file. This is all explained in the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html). Too many questions - ask each separately, to get more helpful help.